# SQL query: get the last row depends on the field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a new problem now. Its all about displaying the result in my database.

Scenario:
I was trying to display the last data in my database `[fldBldgName and fldTotalDuration]`. So, assuming that I have a two data under the fldBldgName and fldTotalDuration.

Example:

```
fldBldgName       fldTotalDuration
bldg1                0:2
bldg1                0:32
bldg1                0:40
bldg1                0:45
bldg2                0:10    
bldg2                0:12
```

As you can see under the fldBldgName have a same building name yet different fldTotalDuration...

I have a problem for displaying it, because in my query the result is

```
fldBldgName        fldTotalDuration
bldg1                  0:2    
bldg2                  0:10
```

this is wrong...

the correct is

```
fldBldgName        fldTotalDuration
bldg1                  0:45
bldg2                  0:12
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE fldNetname = '".$get_radio."' 
    AND fldMonth = '".$get_month."' AND fldWeek = '".$get_week. "' 
    GROUP BY fldBldgName 
    ORDER BY id, fldBldgName, fldTotalDuration DESC
```

Even the ASC is not working....If I include a "DESC LIMIT 1" it will just display only one....I need to display, all unique fldBldgName and the corresponding/last row of fldTotalDuration..

Thanks for help.

Comment: The notion of "last" depends on the ordering of your data.  SQL tables have no inherent order.  How do you determine which record is "last"?

Comment: What datatype is the field `fldTotalDuration`

Comment: What kind of duration is that? I would consider storing it in a different format first.For example seconds as an integer?

Comment: @eggyal...for me.. I need to get the last fldBldgName then also need to get the fldTotalDuration... and now the problem now is how can I get the last fldTotalDuration depends to the fldBldgName

Comment: @RiggsFolly..all of them is TEXT only...

Comment: @PrincessToledo So you will have problems ordering for example 0:2 and 0:10 correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT fldBldgName, MAX(fldTotalDuration) as fldTotalDuration FROM tbldata 
    WHERE fldNetname = '".$get_radio."' 
       AND fldMonth = '".$get_month."' 
       AND fldWeek = '".$get_week. "' 
    GROUP BY fldBldgName 
    ORDER BY id, fldBldgName, fldTotalDuration DESC");
```

Comment: @DieForm...waaaw.! thanks! someone told me that combining the MAX and GROUP BY will make the query ruse...so thats why I didn't try that...So many Thanks! I will check it after 3 mins.. :)